# This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^16.0.0, but Angular version 17.0.6 was found instead

Tags: angular, npm, installation

i download an angular cource repository and since then i am trying to overcome npm i errors
I  overcome most of them but cant find a solution for this:

This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^16.0.0,
but Angular version 17.0.6 was found instead.
want to keep angular 17.0.6' what should i do

help will be appriciated

i tried installing a few angular diffrent versions nothing succeded

Comment: Please, I want to understand your question, is the repository setup with @angular/cli: ^16.0.0 and you want to replace with 17.0.6?

Comment: yes , i dit npm install @angular/cli@17 it dint fix

Comment: Could you share the package.json in the question?